# clojure.test (is (thrown? ...) not seeing exception

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

I have a function `param-values` that throws an `IllegalArgumentException` when it cannot find a key in a Liberator context. I have a **clojure.test** unit test for this:

```
(testing "Non-existing key" 
  (is (thrown? IllegalArgumentException (param-values ctx [:baz]))))
```

For some reason, this test is failing, even though I can see that my function is behaving correctly in the REPL:

```
user> (param-values ctx [:baz])
IllegalArgumentException Missing required param baz  resources/param-value (resources.clj:57)

user> (is (thrown? IllegalArgumentException (param-values ctx [:baz])))

FAIL in clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList@1 (form-init2687593671136401208.clj:1)
expected: (thrown? IllegalArgumentException (param-values ctx [:baz]))
  actual: nil
```

`param-values` itself is quite simple; it just maps over the specified args with `param-value`:

```
(defn param-values [ctx args & [{:keys [optional-args] :as opts}]]
  (let [params (or (get-in ctx [:request :params]) {})
        args (concat args optional-args)]
    (map #(param-value params % opts) args)))
```

Of course, I have more in-depth tests for `param-value`, one of which is:

```
(testing "Arg not present"
    (is (thrown-with-msg?
         IllegalArgumentException #"Missing required param baz"
         (param-value {} :baz))))
```

This test passes!

What gives? Is something about what I'm doing not jiving with the `clojure.test/is` macro? Do I have a typo that I'm too thick to see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it because `param-values` returns a lazy sequence?

When using `thrown-with-msg?` it calls `re-find` on the return value of `(param-value {} :baz)` and thus evaluates the lazy sequence. This does not happen when just using `thrown?` instead.

So could you try this instead:

```
(is (thrown? IllegalArgumentException
      (doall (param-values ctx [:baz]))))
```

`doall` will evaluate the lazy sequence.

---

*Update based on comments*:

As you are not interested in the return value of the lazy sequence, but only the side effects (throwing an exception), it's preferred to use `dorun` instead of `doall`.

Comment: That was exactly it. Thanks a million!